# System.String[] error when posting form C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the System.String[] Error when trying to post data from a form below is my sample code.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox id="AccidentDetailsDate" runat="server" />
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var AccidentDate = Request.Form.GetValues("AccidentDetailsDate");

        Response.Write(AccidentDate);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me over this hurdle it would be much appreciated, I have spent the last 3 hour trying to resolve it!

Comment: "I am getting the System.String[] Error" - what on earth does that mean? What *exactly* is the error, and where?

Comment: Where the value should be returned from the response.write it writes System.String[] where the posted value should be.

Comment: You can for instance write `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",values));`

Answer (score 2):

In the page_load event try the following:

```
var AccidentDate = this.AccidentDetailsDate.Text;
Response.Write(AccidentDate);
```

Since AccidentDetailsDate is a text box you can access it in the code behind using the above syntax.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, because you are getting **array** back, of all form elements named "AccidentDetailsDate".

Sounds like you want a single value:

```
var AccidentDate = Request.Form["AccidentDetailsDate"];
Response.Write(AccidentDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because of line:

```
Response.Write(AccidentDate);
```

Since your `AccidentDate` is a `string[]`, where as [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects a single string value.

The problem is because of the earlier line, you are using `Request.Form.GetValues`, which would return an array of string, You don't have to use `Request.Form`, since your TextBox is already marked as `runat="server"`, you can simply do:

```
var AccidentDate = AccidentDetailsDate.Text;
```

So your code should be:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var AccidentDate = AccidentDetailsDate.Text;
    Response.Write(AccidentDate);
}
```

From the name of the control it appears that you are trying to get `DateTime` from user, you should parse it to `DateTime` in .Net framework or use a `DateTimePicker`

Comment: Brilliant thanks very much for your help. I am currently moving from classic asp to this (to keep my job). Huge learning curve!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ToString()` like this.

`var AccidentDate = Request.Form.GetValues("AccidentDetailsDate").ToString();`
 `Response.Write(AccidentDate);`